# Sorting in mysql should be same as sorting in excel?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sorting, numbers

**Before sorting** in mysql

**|user|**(Column Name)

2-0904-2
52
100
101
102
103
104
108
109
11
112
113
114
12
13
14
15
16
18
2

**After sorting** in mysql

**|user|**(Column Name)

```
2-0904-2<br>
```

52
100
101
102
103
104
108
109
11
112
113
114
12
13
14
15
16
18
2

**Expected result after sorting** as per excel

**|user|**(Column Name)

2-0904-2
2
11
12
13
14
15
16
18
52
100
101
102
103
104
108
109
112
113
114

Comment: hi! welcome to SO, what have you tried so far?

Comment: @Melon simple mysql sort as in "select user from table sort by user ASC"

Comment: `ORDER BY user RLIKE '^[0-9]+$' DESC, user` would first sort by str = numeric value, then by value.

Comment: Hi @Jonny5 i tried the sorting on 
`11,111,12 and 123test` and the result came out `11,111,12,123test` but according to excel it should have been `11,12,111,123test`. **Can i achieve the same sorting somehow?**

Comment: @DanishKundra What about: `ORDER BY user RLIKE '^[0-9]+$' DESC, LENGTH(user), user` ...or: `ORDER BY user RLIKE '^[0-9]+$' DESC, user+0`

Answer (score 1):

In MySQL, you can readily convert a string to a number.  You can also test whether a character is a number.

This should produce the sort you are looking for:

```
order by (left(col, 1) betweeen '0' and '9') desc,
         (col + 0),
         col;
```

The first clause puts the numbers first.  The second converts the leading digits to a number for sorting purposes.  The last orders by the value of the column for strings.

Comment: This the query i tried
query: select * from user_temp order by (left(userName) betweeen '0' and '9') desc, (userName + 0), userName;

This is the error i got
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ') betweeen '0' and '9') desc, (userName + 0), userName' at line 1

Am i missing something?

Comment: @DanishKundra . . . I left out that all important second argument to `left()`.